# How to get all results from an SQL query plus an extra result

Tags: mysql

I am trying to make an sql query that get all the results of people at a certain status (`A.attendance_status_id = 1`) for a particular event, but I also want to include an extra person who may have a different status.

So far I have tried including an OR for just that user_id (`A.user_id = 2`):

```
SELECT A.user_id AS attendeeId, S.name as status, U.first_name as firstName, U.last_name as lastName, A.date_of_interest AS dateOfInterest 
FROM event_attendees as A 
JOIN user as U ON A.user_id = U.id 
JOIN attendance_status as S ON A.attendance_status_id = S.id 
WHERE A.event_id = 3 AND A.attendance_status_id = 1 OR A.user_id = 2 
ORDER BY A.date_of_interest
```

however that includes all of the other events that user is in, when I only want the user status for this particular event.

Is there any way to include that users status to a particular event as well as everyone else who has an `attendence_status_id = 1`?

Thanks

Comment: use parenthesis, roughly: `WHERE event_id AND (attendance OR user_id)`

Answer (score 0):

Add your additional condition in query and try

```
SELECT A.user_id AS attendeeId, S.name as status, U.first_name as firstName, U.last_name as lastName, A.date_of_interest AS dateOfInterest 
FROM event_attendees as A 
JOIN user as U ON A.user_id = U.id 
JOIN attendance_status as S ON A.attendance_status_id = S.id 
WHERE (A.event_id = 3 AND A.attendance_status_id = 1) OR (A.user_id = 2 and ADDITIONAL_CONDITION)
ORDER BY A.date_of_interest
```